# PHP Regex get the value from JavaScript code

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with designing a regular expression to extract a value from JavaScript code.
I need to find the line where `Array('38')` is and get the numeric value of the `Math.floor` function's argument there.

Given this code, the result would be `296`:

```
addCombination(158, new Array('38'), -9, Math.floor(296), 0, -1, 'LB229');
addCombination(159, new Array('39'), -2, Math.floor(221), 0, -1, 'LB201');
addCombination(160, new Array('40'), -2, Math.floor(201), 0, -1, 'LB243');
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you need to obtain? The *result* of `Math.floor(296)` if a line contains `Array('38')`? Or the substring `Math.floor(296)`?

Comment: hi, i need to extract number 296 from the Math.floor(296) if the line contains Array('38'). Great thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this through a single regex.

```
^(?=.*\bArray\('38'\)).*?\bMath\.floor\(\K\d+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uJ0cJ3/1)

- `(?=.*\bArray\('38'\))` would match at the start of a line only if the line contains the text  `Array('38')`.
- And the following `.*?\bMath\.floor\(` matches all the chars on that line from the start until `Match.floor(` string.
- `\K` discards the previous  match.
- `\d+` matches the number present inside the `Math.floor` function.

**Example:**

```
$s = <<<EOT
addCombination(158, new Array('38'), -9, Math.floor(296), 0, -1, 'LB229');
addCombination(159, new Array('39'), -2, Math.floor(221), 0, -1, 'LB201');
addCombination(160, new Array('40'), -2, Math.floor(201), 0, -1, 'LB243');
EOT;
preg_match_all("~^(?=.*\bArray\('38'\)).*?\bMath\.floor\(\K\d+~m", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 296
)
```

Comment: strange... it won't work like php string... $regex = "/^(?=.*\bArray\('38'\)).*?\bMath\.floor\(\K\d+/";

Comment: enable multiline modifier.

Comment: Since you're new to this site, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example PHP code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVU94WmtNbTFsRUk) you might use to extract the `Math.floor`s:

```
<?php
   $str = "addCombination(158, new Array('38'), -9, Math.floor(296), 0, -1, 'LB229');\naddCombination(159, new Array('38'), -2, Math.floor(221), 0, -1, 'LB201');\naddCombination(160, new Array('38'), -2, Math.floor(201), 0, -1, 'LB243');";
   preg_match_all("/Math\\.floor\\(\\K\\d+(?=\\))/", $str, $matches);
   foreach ($matches[0] as $line)
   {
       echo $line . "\n";
   }
?>
```

Output:

```
296                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
221                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
201
```

Comment: hi, this one not working, as string ir from the few lines and preg_match extrancting just value of first line...

Comment: ok, but there we've got array, the question is to get values from separate lines, for example if array('38') then extracted value 296; if array('39') then - 221;  if array('40') then - 201;

Comment: I updated the code. Now, it seems working as expected.